# My vba code wouldn't auto start why?

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest, ms-word

even as i click enable macros, it still wouldnt auto start

```
Private Sub DownloadXLFileFromURL()

    Dim myURL As String, sFilename As String
    myURL = "URL"
    sFilename = Environ("SystemDrive") & Environ("HomePath") & _
            Application.PathSeparator & "Desktop" & Application.PathSeparator & _
            "Filename.ext"

    Dim WinHttpReq As Object, oStream As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False ', "username", "password"
   WinHttpReq.Send

    myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile sFilename, 2  ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
       oStream.Close
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you done so that code is automatically launched? Because as far as we can see there is nothing here that will launched that code except for a manual intervention... And maybe you can also explain when you want the code to be launched, please details more your question (read this to help you :  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an `Document_Open` event handler to `ThisDocument`. This code will be fired when you open the document. Here you can call your method.

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    DownloadXLFileFromURL
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a vbs script inside my vba code, so that it can be saved on the desktop and then run the vbs code from the desktop? All with macro